# A simple Try/catch doesn't working

Tags: exception, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This is my code, it's very simple:

```
$TargetFolder = 'M:\'

try{

$Getfolderlist = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq 'old' }

}catch {

Write-Host "Error ! :) "    

}
```

It doesn't work and I get an powershell exception:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'M' does not exist.
At C:\ef-scripts\PurgeDeliveryZip\purge_delivery_zip.ps1:23 char:18
+ $Getfolderlist = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -an ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (M:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need -ErrorAction set to Stop. This way the catch block gets the exception. Read about try catch usage here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx

Also, you may want to read about terminating errors in PowerShell and [ErrorAction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) common parameter helps.

```
$TargetFolder = 'M:\'

try{
$Getfolderlist = Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse -Ea Stop | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq 'old' }
}
catch {
Write-Host "Error ! :) "    
}
```